# Storage question. On topic?

Tags: discussion

I should probably know the answer to this and I'm thinking the answer is no but would the following question be on topic

I have an environment with Live, User Acceptance, staging and development servers (In this case windows mainly 2012, all hyper-v guests). Each of these parts of the environment has a frontend and backend server. The backend servers contain proportionally large amounts of data. Across the User Acceptance, staging and development servers this data does not change (apart from the occasional refresh from live) and it rarely accessed outside the development cycle.

In this type of environment what is the best way of avoiding wasting storage space on static and rarely accessed data.

Things I've considered.

Deleting servers while not in use
Deleting data discs while not in use
Sharing data discs between servers

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I assume you know that questions about storage are on-topic and therefore your concern is with how the question has been presented.

> In this type of environment what is the best way of avoiding wasting storage space on static and rarely accessed data.

Questions that ask what the "best" way is to do something invite closure as opinion-based because being best is a matter of opinion.

However, asking "how" to minimize storage space consumption given the particulars of your environment is on-topic. Technology exists that solves this very problem and good answers will be able to cite such facts accordingly.

Edit your question to remove the request for the subjective "best" solution and you should be good to go.